# Как сделать точку в 4px

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как увеличить размер точек, никак не могу разобраться.

```js
var
  container,
  particle,
  canvas,
  ctx,
  a, b,
  n,
  w, h,
  p;
particle = {
  x: 10,
  y: 0
};

function init() {
  container = document.getElementById('containers');
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  w = 50;
  h = 50;
  container.style.marginLeft = Math.round(w * -0.5) + 'px';
  container.style.marginTop = Math.round(h * -0.5) + 'px';
  p = Object.create(particle);
  p.x = p.ox = 25;
  p.y = p.oy = 25;

  container.appendChild(canvas);
}

function step() {
    b = (a = ctx.createImageData(w, h)).data;

    b[n = (~~p.x + ~~p.y * w) * 4] = b[n + 1] = b[n + 2] = 255, b[n + 3] = 255;

    ctx.putImageData(a, 0, 0);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
init();
step();
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #000;
}

#containers {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="containers"></div>
```

Comment: нужно смотреть на строку: `b[n = (~~p.x + ~~p.y * w) * 4] = b[n + 1] = b[n + 2] = COLOR, b[n + 3] = 255;` - в ней устанавливается цвет для конкретной точки, если нужно не одну точку разукрасить - нужно установить цвет для нескольких точек

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код** для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @Kromster, так вроде код дан, ожидаемое поведение описано

Comment: @Kromster, вполне небольшой: из того что можно убрать только навешивание события mousemove, да проверку Stats, все остальное - тупая отрисовка точек, и именно по ней и вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy приведенный код избыточен и на 80% не относится к теме вопроса "Как сделать точки в 4px".

Comment: @Kromster, можешь сделать пример убрав все ненужное?

Comment: @Grundy без IDE конечно не так удобно, но, для начала, вот так лишнее можно выкинуть ^

Comment: @Kromster, как вариант :-) спасибо